# determine any screen capturing during my java application is running

Tags: java, desktop-application

I want make a desktop application using java swing or javafx for showing video tutorials.
As the client must purche a CD of a particular tutorial and I dont want that anyone capture the videos within the application using some capturing softwares,I decided to determine any capturing action while the program is running (even print screen actions) and there is any capturing action add a dark panel on top of all elements to prevent capturing.
I've seen a software that when a capturing action is started do the above action to prevent recording videos

Comment: Your approach is technically flawed. As long as the client is able to **see** the video, they are also able to **record** it. If not anything else, they can always record the screen with their phone or plug the video cable in a recording device. So one way or another, they will do it if they really want. But I am quite sure that you will not have a problem with people wanting to steal your videos, you will have a problem with convincing people that your videos are even worth watching.

Comment: Im living in a country that copy right rules are not accepted so if someone record that video I will face with a failure.Also recording using physical devices may make an unpleasant feeling for viewer and make the size of movie greater.I think this approach will decrease the chance of failure as one of examples that I mentioned which used this approach and no one share its videos because recording via physical devices is harder than and has environment voices on the another hand recording from desktop sharing applications like anydesk

Comment: Will take many internet packets which makes the recording process very expensive

Comment: I don't think there's any way for a Java application to tell whether the screen is being captured.

Comment: I think what you are actually looking for is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management but I have not idea whether there are technical solutions for Java.

Comment: If you’ve seen software refuse to show video when capturing is in effect, I’m guessing it did something laughably fragile like regularly checking the system’s process list for known capture programs.  Like most attempts by software to control how the user users their hardware, this is so easy to circumvent, it’s not worth doing.

Comment: Your approach is  thank you